# Why does my .cshtml page not find images with local paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

I have two variables that I use as paths for different pictures. One path is local, the other is on the internet.

The local image does not work, no matter what I do to the local path.

- I have tried putting the image in the same folder as the .cshtml
  page.
- I have tried reversing the slashes in the file-path.
- I have tried using abbreviated paths.
- I have tried to refer to it through
  @Url.Content("~/Images/Image1.png").
- I have tried putting the image file in wwwroot.

It does not work when I load the index.html in the wwwroot with the localhost, but it does work when I load the index.html with the index.html path

Put shortly: Why does path variable 'firstImgSource' work and not 'secondImgSource'.

[Code example](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/885800481056759828/945283550507307048/unknown.png)

Comment: Is your local image in a folder in your solution? Those are not, by default, copied to the build path when compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `src` attribute of the `img` element accepts a URL, not a file path. The URL can be absolute or relative. If the image is part of your Razor Pages application, the images should be placed in the web content root, which is the *wwwroot* folder. Your relative path should not include "wwwroot". So if you place an image in a folder named `images` within *wwwroot*, the relative path is `/images/my-image.png`

Comment: Thanks Mike, this answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

The first one working because its image from Web URL. You have some problems with your path for sure.
Try to use relative path.
For example: `src="~/images/BabyMother.png"`

Comment: The tilde sign does not work for some reason. I know that ~/ is supposed to refer to the root folder, but it doesn't for me. It would be great to know why it does not work, but that's another question. This issue is resolved, thanks for the help.

Comment: Then try to use dots for go back, the whole point of my answer is that, just try to use relative path. Nice, your welcome!